# quotients by quasi-coherent ideal sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I saw this lemma stated in some lecture notes:

If $\mathcal{I}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals on a scheme $X$ and if $U$ is any affine open subset of $X$, then $\frac{\tilde{\mathcal{O}_X}}{\mathcal{I}}(U) = \frac{\mathcal{O}_X(U)}{\mathcal{I}(U)}$.

I am curious if this is true for ideal sheaves which are not quasi-coherent? I also wonder if $U$ has to be affine? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample for $U$ not affine:

Put $U=\mathbb P^1_k$ and fix some point $p\in U$.
Then for $ \mathcal I=\mathcal O(-2p) $ we have  $\frac{\mathcal O}{\mathcal I}(U)= k^2$, since $\frac{\mathcal O}{\mathcal I}$ is a skyscraper sheaf with stalk $k^2$ at $p$.
However $\frac{\mathcal O(U)}{\mathcal I(U)}=\frac {k}{0}=k$.